# I'm getting segmentation fault using fseek()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, project

Here is the code that is giving me the error of Segmentation fault..

```
void hire_skill()
{
    int linec = 0;
    FILE *p;
    p = fopen("/home/suraj/Coding/PBL/Details/hiree.txt", "r");
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nFile did not open\n");
    }

    char c;
    c = fgetc(p);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            linec++;
        }
        c = fgetc(p);
    }
    fclose(p);
    printf("\nNumber of lines :\t%d\n", linec);

    FILE *ptrr;
    ptrr = fopen("/home/suraj/Coding/PBL/Details/hiree.txt", "r");
    if (ptrr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nFile did not open\n");
    }
    rewind(ptrr);
    for (int i = 0; i < linec; i++)
    {
        fscanf(ptrr, "%s", hiree_login[i].name);
        fscanf(ptrr, "%d", hiree_login[i].age);
        fscanf(ptrr, "%s", hiree_login[i].gender);
        fscanf(ptrr, "%d", hiree_login[i].uid);
        fscanf(ptrr, "%s", hiree_login[i].skill);
        fscanf(ptrr, "%lld", hiree_login[i].phno);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < linec; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s, %d, %s, %d, %s, %lld\n", hiree_login[i].name, hiree_login[i].age, hiree_login[i].gender, hiree_login[i].uid, hiree_login[i].skill, hiree_login[i].phno);
    }
    fclose(ptrr);
}
```

And here is the structure i'm using to get values from the file and store it

```
struct hireeLogin
{
    int age;
    char name[20];
    char gender[1];
    int uid;
    char skill[20];
    long long int phno;
} hiree_login[MAX1]; //MAX1 = 50..

The whole code is on my github account : https://github.com/Suru-web/PBL/blob/main/Emp.c
```

I tried a few irrelevant things, but none of them worked. maybe i dont know much about this, so i would like anyone to help me fix my code. Thank you!!

Comment: Start by specifying max string lengths for `fscanf` `%s`. Remember to account for string terminator! Also add checking for parse errors with `fscanf`. It's important documentstion reading skill to be able to figure how to do these two things from docs of `fscanf`, so I suggest you try yourself before using any answer someone may write here.

Comment: Post an example of the contents of _"hiree.txt"_

Comment: Your posted code does not contain any calls to `fseek()`.  Why is that in the title?  And `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  Putting the value returned from `fgetc()` into a `char` makes detection of `EOF` unreliable because `EOF` is an `int` value that cannot be represented as a `char` (on almost all C implementations).

Comment: Post all that is needed to inform those who would try to answer your questions.  In this case providing a [mcve] is preferable and more likely to result in good help then directing people to go and search through your gihub

Comment: `fscanf(p, "%d", hiree_login[i].age);` -> `fscanf(p, "%d", &hiree_login[i].age);` note the added addressof (`&`) operator, do this for the numeric inputs, the strings wont need it, this is because the `%d` specifier expects a pointer to the destination variable, not its value.

Comment: `char gender[1];` followed by `scanf("%s", gender)` does not end well.

Comment: thank you @anastaciu '&" was missing in every fscanf statement for integers.. its solved now..

Comment: The reason char array arguments don't need the addressof operator is because when you pass them as arguments they already are pointers to it's first element, FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line ,

```
fscanf(p, "%s", hiree_login[i].name);
```

File pointer `p` is already closed. You may need to use `ptrr`

Comment: @SurajGMeharwade - To what exact error are you referring?  There are potentially many errors, and without editing your post to provide the specific information needed, you are asking people to guess.    Why do you point to `fseek` as the source of the error in your title, but do not include it in the text of your post?

Answer (score 1):

`gender` is an array of size 1 and can therefore hold a string of up to length 0.  In the line `fscanf(ptrr, "%s", hiree_login[i].gender);`, `scanf` is probably writing more than zero characters into the buffer, so the behavior is undefined.

Never use `"%s"` in a format string.  Always use a width modifier that is no more than one less than the size of the buffer.